# Regrouping and mutating dataframe with multiple very specific conditions in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-wrangling

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2023-02-12', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-14',
           '2023-02-12', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-14',
           '2023-03-06', '2023-03-07', '2023-03-08',
           '2023-03-07', '2023-03-08', '2023-03-09')),
  PID = c(1091, 1091, 1091,
          2091, 2091, 2091,
          1137, 1137, 1137, 
          2137, 2137, 2137),
  give = c('a', 'c', 'e',
           'aa', 'cc', 'ee',
           'aaa', 'ccc', 'eee',
           'aaaa', 'cccc', 'eeee'),
  receive = c('b', 'd', 'f',
              'bb', 'dd', 'ff',
              'bbb', 'ddd', 'fff',
              'bbbb', 'dddd', 'ffff')
)
```

I want to regroup and relabel the columns in the dataframe such that this is the output:

```
  example_solution <- data.frame(

  date = as.Date(c('2023-02-12', '2023-02-13', '2023-02-14',
                   '2023-03-06', '2023-03-07', '2023-03-08', '2023-03-09')),
  CID = c(91, 91, 91, 
          137, 137, 137, 137),
  PID_A = c(1091, 1091, 1091,
          1137, 1137, 1137, NA),
  PID_B = c(2091, 2091, 2091,
            NA, 2137, 2137, 2137),
  give_A = c('a', 'c', 'e',
             'aaa', 'ccc', 'eee', NA),
  receive_B = c('bb', 'dd', 'ff',
                NA, 'bbbb', 'dddd', 'ffff'),
  give_B = c('aa', 'cc', 'ee',
           NA, 'aaaa', 'cccc', 'eeee'),
  receive_A = c('b', 'd', 'f',
              'bbb', 'ddd', 'fff', NA)
)
```

I have some functional code so far that does most of the job:

```
example <- example %>% 
  group_by(CID = sub('.', '', PID), date) %>% 
  mutate(name = LETTERS[1:n()]) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = PID:receive) %>%
  relocate(receive_A, .after = give_B) %>%
  relocate(receive_B, .after = give_A)
```

The only problem is that when there is a date where there is only an entry for the `CID` with the `PID` starting with 2 and not 1 (i.e. 2137 on `date` 2023-03-09 in this case), 2137 is grouped as `PID_A` instead of `PID_B`. ffff is also grouped under `give_A` instead of `receive_B` and eeee is grouped under `receive_A` instead of `give_B`.

Essentially, data for all PIDs that start with 2 should always be associated the column names `whatevername_B`, even if there is no corresponding PID that start with 1 on the same date.

Does anyone know how I can get to the desired output?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the column `name` is defined using `n()`, which evaluates to `1` in the case of the date `2023-03-09` since there is only one row inside of `example` corresponding to this date. Hence, the suffix `_A` gets assigned.

If the requirement is "data for all PIDs that start with `2` should always be associated the column names `whatevername_B`" then we have to take this into account when defining `name`. This can be achieved e.g. by replacing `mutate(name = LETTERS[1:n()])`:

```
example %>%
    group_by(CID = sub('.', '', PID), date) %>%
    mutate(name = case_when(substr(PID, 1, 1) == "2" ~ "B",
                            TRUE ~ LETTERS[1:n()])) %>%
    pivot_wider(values_from = PID:receive) %>%
    relocate(receive_A, .after = give_B) %>%
    relocate(receive_B, .after = give_A)
```

Then the output will look like:

```
# A tibble: 7 × 8
# Groups:   CID, date [7]
  date       CID   PID_A PID_B give_A receive_B give_B receive_A
  <date>     <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>    
1 2023-02-12 091    1091  2091 a      bb        aa     b        
2 2023-02-13 091    1091  2091 c      dd        cc     d        
3 2023-02-14 091    1091  2091 e      ff        ee     f        
4 2023-03-06 137    1137    NA aaa    NA        NA     bbb      
5 2023-03-07 137    1137  2137 ccc    bbbb      aaaa   ddd      
6 2023-03-08 137    1137  2137 eee    dddd      cccc   fff      
7 2023-03-09 137      NA  2137 NA     ffff      eeee   NA
```

Comment: You have no idea how helpful this was. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

```
library(tidyverse)
example %>%
   mutate(name= LETTERS[as.numeric(str_sub(PID, 1,1))],
          CID = str_sub(PID, -2)) %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(date, CID), 
               values_from = c(give, receive),  names_vary = 'slowest')

# A tibble: 7 × 6
  date       CID   give_A receive_A give_B receive_B
  <date>     <chr> <chr>  <chr>     <chr>  <chr>    
1 2023-02-12 91    a      b         aa     bb       
2 2023-02-13 91    c      d         cc     dd       
3 2023-02-14 91    e      f         ee     ff       
4 2023-03-06 37    aaa    bbb       NA     NA       
5 2023-03-07 37    ccc    ddd       aaaa   bbbb     
6 2023-03-08 37    eee    fff       cccc   dddd     
7 2023-03-09 37    NA     NA        eeee   ffff
```

Take note that the following is sufficient to solve the problem:

```
example %>%
   mutate(name = str_sub(PID, 1,1), CID = str_sub(PID, -2)) %>%
   pivot_wider(id_cols = c(date, CID), values_from = c(give, receive))

# A tibble: 7 × 6
  date       CID   give_1 give_2 receive_1 receive_2
  <date>     <chr> <chr>  <chr>  <chr>     <chr>    
1 2023-02-12 91    a      aa     b         bb       
2 2023-02-13 91    c      cc     d         dd       
3 2023-02-14 91    e      ee     f         ff       
4 2023-03-06 37    aaa    NA     bbb       NA       
5 2023-03-07 37    ccc    aaaa   ddd       bbbb     
6 2023-03-08 37    eee    cccc   fff       dddd     
7 2023-03-09 37    NA     eeee   NA        ffff
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join

```r
library(dplyr)
dfs <- 
  example %>% 
  mutate(CID = PID %% 1000, .after = date) %>% 
  split(~PID %/% 1000)

full_join(dfs[[1]], dfs[[2]], by = c("date", "CID"), suffix = c("_A", "_B"))
#>         date CID PID_A give_A receive_A PID_B give_B receive_B
#> 1 2023-02-12  91  1091      a         b  2091     aa        bb
#> 2 2023-02-13  91  1091      c         d  2091     cc        dd
#> 3 2023-02-14  91  1091      e         f  2091     ee        ff
#> 4 2023-03-06 137  1137    aaa       bbb    NA   <NA>      <NA>
#> 5 2023-03-07 137  1137    ccc       ddd  2137   aaaa      bbbb
#> 6 2023-03-08 137  1137    eee       fff  2137   cccc      dddd
#> 7 2023-03-09 137    NA   <NA>      <NA>  2137   eeee      ffff
```

In base R it's not all that different:

```
dfs <- 
  example |> 
  transform(CID = PID %% 1000) |>
  split(~PID %/% 1000)

merge(dfs[[1]], dfs[[2]], by = c("date", "CID"), suffixes = c("_A", "_B"), all = TRUE)
#>         date CID PID_A give_A receive_A PID_B give_B receive_B
#> 1 2023-02-12  91  1091      a         b  2091     aa        bb
#> 2 2023-02-13  91  1091      c         d  2091     cc        dd
#> 3 2023-02-14  91  1091      e         f  2091     ee        ff
#> 4 2023-03-06 137  1137    aaa       bbb    NA   <NA>      <NA>
#> 5 2023-03-07 137  1137    ccc       ddd  2137   aaaa      bbbb
#> 6 2023-03-08 137  1137    eee       fff  2137   cccc      dddd
#> 7 2023-03-09 137    NA   <NA>      <NA>  2137   eeee      ffff
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>