# Exchanging values across columns in R based on specific condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks something like this:

```
example <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2023-03-05', 
                   '2023-02-24', '2023-02-25',
                   '2023-03-01', '2023-03-02', 
                   '2023-03-03', 
                   '2023-03-04')),
  CID = c(137,
          157, 157,
          222, 222,
          133,
          260),
  PID_A = c(2137,
            2157, 2157,
            2222, 2222,
            1133,
            1260),
  PID_B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2260),
  give_A = c('a', NA, 'b',
             'c', 'd', 'e', 'g'),
  receive_B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'f', 'h'),
  rating_1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  rating_2 = c(2,5,6,2,3,1,1)
)
```

I want to modify the dataframe such that if and only if `PID_A` starts with a '2' AND `PID_B` is NA, shift the value in `PID_A` to `PID_B` and exchange the text in `give_A` with `receive_B`.

This is the example output:

```
example_solution <- data.frame(
  date = as.Date(c('2023-03-05', 
                   '2023-02-24', '2023-02-25',
                   '2023-03-01', '2023-03-02', 
                   '2023-03-03', 
                   '2023-03-04')),
  CID = c(137,
          157, 157,
          222, 222,
          133,
          260),
  PID_A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
            1133,
            1260),
  PID_B = c(2137,
            2157, 2157,
            2222, 2222, NA, 2260),
  give_A = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 'e', 'g'),
  receive_B = c('a', NA, 'b',
                'c', 'd', 'f', 'h'),
  rating_1 = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
  rating_2 = c(2,5,6,2,3,1,1)
)
```

Does anyone know an efficient way to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: is this question an extension of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591435/regrouping-and-mutating-dataframe-with-multiple-very-specific-conditions-in-r? if so it seems you are solving in-between problem rather than solving the true problem. Better start from the first datafram to the final one instead of  starting from the intermediate df. Also consider asking the main problem rather than asking an [xy problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Hi @Onyambu, you're right that this is an in-between problem! I am asking this question because the `ratings` columns is given to me in an order that corresponds to the inefficient dataframe (i.e. the dataframe I was trying to resolve in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76591435/regrouping-and-mutating-dataframe-with-multiple-very-specific-conditions-in-r). I believe my question in this post is the most efficient way to resolve it in this situation, though I am open to being corrected! In other words, if there is still a solution to this specific question, I would love to know.

Comment: Start woth you have, ask on how to get to what you want. Explain your thought process and how each value is obtained. Leave the coding to SO.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I could find of doing this is using a for loop:

```
processor <- function(df) {
for (row in seq_along(df[-1])) { # oddly, seq_along(df) returns a vector one longer than the number of rows in df???
  if (substr(df[row, 'PID_A'], 1, 1) == '2' &
      is.na(df[row, 'PID_B'])) {
    new_b <- df[row, 'PID_A']
    df[row, 'PID_A'] <- df[row, 'PID_B']
    df[row, 'PID_B'] <- new_b
    new_give <- df[row, 'give_A']
    df[row, 'give_A'] <- df[row, 'receive_B']
    df[row, 'receive_B'] <- new_give
  }
}
return(df)
}
processor(example)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my base R solution with `within`:

```
example_solution <- within(example, {
  ind <- startsWith(as.character(PID_A),"2")&is.na(PID_B)
  PID_B[ind] <- PID_A[ind]
  PID_A[ind] <- NA
  g <- give_A[ind]
  give_A[ind] <- receive_B[ind]
  receive_B[ind] <- g
  rm(g, ind)
})
```